# How do I get buttons in html to not move when I increase the font size of the buttons?

Tags: html, css

I want to have my buttons get bigger when I hover over them but when they get bigger all of my other buttons shift to the side and I want that to not happen but I don't know how to do that. In case this helps, this is the code I have to make it bigger:

```
<style> 
    button{transition-duration: 0.7s;} button:hover{font-size:20px;} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just changing the font-size, you could use the `transform: scale` property to scale your buttons on hover.

```css
button { transition-duration: 0.25s; }
button:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

```html
<button>Button1</button>
<button>Button2</button>
<button>Button3</button>
```